# Django model attribute value evaluation in callable

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why in this two attributes of the `upload` model, `time` is evaluated every time 
I add a new instance but `string` does not change at all? (`inUnixTime` gives me the current datetime in unix time)

```
class upload(models.Model):

    #...
    time = models.IntegerField(default=inUnixTime)
    string = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=str(inUnixTime()))
    #...

def inUnixTime(t=None):
    if not t:
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
    return int(time.mktime(t.timetuple()))
```

PS. If I use only the callable, doing a

```
string = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=str(inUnixTime))
```

then I get the memory address of the object and not the unix time as a string.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str(inUnixTime())` returns a string, just like `u'A string'` - it's not a callable, so it won't change. When you use the `inUnixTime` function as a default, it is a callable so it gets called each time.

What you probably want is this:

```
def string_default():
    return str(inUnixTime())
```

and then:

```
string = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=string_default)
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, you don't know how many hours I have spent on that... Thank you very much... I will also give you an up vote not only acceptance...

Comment: However, I have to un-tick the acceptance I gave you because of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default which says that "...lambdas cannot be used for field options like default because they cannot be serialized by migrations.".

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. That changed in 1.7 when django migrations were introduced. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this is to combine @Greg 's answer and  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default  wrapping lambda in a callable.

Comment: This answer was posted before @Greg altered his answer, that is why it refers to lambda. Greg's initial answer used lambda.. which if you wrap it in a callable it works...so I do not understand why the down vote...